# How to update saved api results

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm building a c# application that uses tasks. I am using an api to get some information that multiple tasks need:

```
public class API
{
    private readonly Hashtable _values;
    public API(){
        _values = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
    }

    public float GetValue(string request)
    {
         if(_values.Contains(request))
            return _values["request"];
         else //call api
    }
}
```

I don't want to put lock on the whole method (GetValue) since there are many different requests. I want only tasks that have request which needs an api call, wait for the call. Other tasks can get the value from the _values hashtable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't build cache by yourself, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- Cache `Task` itself not result
- Check this code https://github.com/MaximTkachenko/cache-once/blob/master/src/Mtk.CacheOnce/MemoryCacheOnceExtensions.cs (it looks similar to what you need)